# CORS Allow Origin Not Matching Origin error through NGINX

Tags: nginx, cors, azure-aks, istio, servicemesh

I have one application on one domain that talks to another application through browser making API calls. Its getting below error in the devtools logs

`CORS Allow Origin Not Matching Origin`

The route it takes is through 3 servers before it hits the application which is hosted in AKS.
First it hits an nginx TLS server and here I have enabled CORS like so underneath the location block

```
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://mysite.domain';
      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE";
      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, Content-Type";
```

Next it gets forwarded on to an nginx reverse proxy server which has the same config defined under the location block

Next it hits the service mesh (istio) in AKS where the virtual service it hits has the below configuration for CORS

```
  - corsPolicy:
      allowCredentials: true
      allowHeaders:
      - authorization
      - content-type
      allowMethods:
      - GET
      - POST
      - OPTIONS
      - PUT
      - DELETE
      allowOrigins:
      - exact: '*'
```

If I bypass my nginx servers then I dont have any issue but when I target the service through the nginx servers I get the above CORS error. Looking at the devtool logs and the failure in detail it makes no sense as I can see the CORS policy of all three hops is identical and the access-control-allow-origin is the same for all of them and it exactly matches the Origin field in the same request.

I have tried many combinations including allowing ALL on the nginx servers like below

`add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';`

And I also tried locking it down to the URL on the virtual service in K8S but that didnt work either